# Usefull aliases in ".bash_profile"?

Tags: linux, bash

E.g.:

```
echo 'alias myip="curl -s "http://checkip.dyndns.org/" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | head -1"' >> /home/USER/.bash_profile
```

when I type "myip" then I will get my public IP address

Comment: Whatever you regularly would type anyway. Better ask for useful bash commands, but I'm pretty sure that's already available somewhere.

Comment: Do you *only* want aliases, or are functions acceptable?

Comment: functions could come too, yes!! :)

Comment: You should generally put aliases in ~/.bashrc and not in ~/.bash_profile because aliases are not exported and hence not inherited by child shells.

Comment: If you Google .bashrc you will find tons of samples. When I was learning unix initially I found these and copied in quite a few to my .bashrc file. After some time I slowly trimmed down what i had added because I had no clue of some of the functionality of the things i had added. I then started adding shorcuts to commands i would use daily but where too long to type out repetitively. You sort of defeat the purpose of creating the aliases if you have to study to alias file to figure out what a particular command does.

Comment: Even simpler: `curl ip.appspot.com`

Comment: `alias myip='curl ip.appspot.com'` in `.bash_profile` for IP.  `alias flushDNS='dscacheutil -flushcache'`.  `alias ds_store="find . -type f -name '*.DS_Store' -ls -delete"` Recursive delete `.DS_Store` files.  `alias showfiles='defaults write com.apple.finder ShowAllFiles TRUE'
alias hidefiles='defaults write com.apple.finder ShowAllFiles FALSE'` Toggle hidden files.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few of my aliases.

when I want to open a file with the GUI, i type `go filename`

```
alias go='xdg-open'
```

reccords the desktop with ffmpeg, and save to the specified file

```
alias recordDesktop='ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 800x600 -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq'
```

Starts a simple http server with python

```
alias simpleServer='python -m SimpleHTTPServer'
```

Color in grep :

```
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

Aliases for ls

```
alias ldir='ls -d */'
alias lgrep='ls | grep'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias lx='ls -CFlash'
```

Start and stop lampp

```
alias lamppstart='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start'
alias lamppstop='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop'
```

sl is always fun when you typo ls, but you want to be able to interrupt it, since it's not interruptable by default.

```
alias sl='sl -e'
```

Aliases for the vim server

```
alias vimc='vim --remote-tab-silent'
alias vims='vim --servername VIM'
```

I have this in my `~/.bash_functions`, to scrape files from a website :

```
function wget_scrape {
   wget -r -l1 -np -A.$1 -nd $2
}
```

just a note, if you have many aliases, you may want to define them in `~/.bash_aliases`, and add this somewhere in `~/.bashrc` (i think it's there by default in ubuntu) :

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
     . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: recordDesktop.. nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only one I have that I really care about (doesn't *always* do a perfect job though):

```
cless() {
  echo -en '\033]2;Viewing: '"$1"'\007' 1>&2
  pygmentize -f terminal "$1" | less -R
}
```